# TIMESTAMP To DATE in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a column called Create_Date which has data in the format like `19-JUN-18 10.27.00.000000000 PM` and data type is `TIMESTAMP(6)`.

I am trying to look at date range like yesterday's date or between two dates in Create_Date without using `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(P.CREATE_DATE_TIME,'dd/mon/yy'))` and entering the value as `'19-JUN-18'`.

I want to use `Create_Date=SYSDATE-1` OR `Create_Date=CURRENT_DATE-1` instead to filter on yesterdays date. Or Use `Create_Date>=SYSDATE` or `Create_Date>=CURRENT_DATE` to look at dates greater than or equal to today.

Can someone help?

Comment: Dates and timestamps don't have any intrinsic format; you're just seeing them however your client decides to format them, often based on your NLS settings. I'd also avoid using `YY` in a format model, or relying on implicit conversions.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `TRUNC`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE Create_Date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE,'DD')  -- -1

-- or between to dates (using date literals)
WHERE Create_Date >= DATE 'yyyy-mm-dd'
   AND Create_Date < DATE 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the default behavior is for `trunc`, but I generally provide the granularity: `trunc(Create_Date, 'DD')` would truncate the date to the day.

Comment: @TravisHegner It is default :) **[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=32392ac489aa746f12dd0a9dfcf5427f)** But you are right, EIBTI rule is very important

Answer (score 2):

As it's a timestamp I'd cast the truncated (to midnight) current date to a timestamp for clarity; Oracle will use an index on that column even if you leave it as a date, but it doesn't hurt to make it explicit:

```
where create_date >= cast(trunc(sysdate) as timestamp)
```

[The `trunc()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TRUNC-date.html) defaults to truncating to midnight; you can explicitly include `'DD'` as a second argument if you prefer (for even more clarity, though some would see it as noise).

If you want a range, say yesterday:

```
where create_date >= cast(trunc(sysdate) - 1 as timestamp)
and create_date < cast(trunc(sysdate) as timestamp)
```

If you want to specify other dates then you can use timestamp literals, e.g. to see everything for May:

```
where create_date >= timestamp '2018-05-01 00:00:00'
and create_date < timestamp '2018-06-01 00:00:00'
```